Intercepting image.src assignment
I need to remap, from a single-page application client's side, the request of several resources.
I can intercept the requests of resources that are loaded through fetch in this way
const {fetch: originalFetch} = window;

window.fetch = async (...args) => 
{
 let [resource, config ] = args;

 resource = resource.replace("www.somewhere", "www.elsewhere");
 const response = await originalFetch(resource, config);
 
 return response;
};

However, there's a billion pieces of code where images (and video, and audio files for that matter) are loaded by simple assignment
var image = new Image();

image.onload = 
function()
{
 // something happens here
}

image.src = "www.somewhere.com/hello.jpg";

Is there any way to intercept assignments and operate on src before the actual request is processed?

You need to create Proxy objects for the objects you want to monitor.

You could monkeypatch the setter:


var image = new Image();

const {set, ...def} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Image.prototype, 'src');
Object.assign(def, {
  set(val){
    console.log(val);
    set.call(this, val);
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(Image.prototype, 'src', def);

image.src = "www.somewhere.com/hello.jpg";



